# Backspace doesn't remove letters in the input field?

Tags: javascript

I'm making some sort of simple encrypter where A becomes B, B becomes C in the 'decrypted' input field. However, backspace doesn't work and doesn't remove any letters in the 'encrypted' input field.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="decrypted" type="text">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input id="encrypted" type="text">
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
let letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'Backspace', ' '];
let letterNumber = 0

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    console.log(e.key)
    letterNumber = letters.lastIndexOf(e.key)
    encrypt()
    }
)

function encrypt() {
    
    if (letterNumber <= 25) {
        letterNumber ++
        document.getElementById('encrypted').value += letters[letterNumber]
    }
    else if (letterNumber == 27) {
        document.getElementById('encrypted').value --
    }
console.log(letters[letterNumber])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your event handler for the input

```js
console.log(letters.lastIndexOf(e.key))
```

You will see that the value is `26`. The function `encrypt` does not include condition for this.

Additionally the code `document.getElementById('encrypted').value --` will not work. You are not operating on numbers so that will just create `NaN`. I suggest doing sth like

```js
const value = document.getElementById('encrypted').value
const truncatedValue = value.slice(0, value.length - 1)
```